# Recibo este error al compilar un proyecto: error: cannot find symbol method setLatestEventInfo

Tags: android, android-studio

Este es el error 1:

```
  error: cannot find symbol method 
  setLatestEventInfo(MySimpleNotification,CharSequence,
  CharSequence,PendingIntent)
```

Parte del código de ese error

```
      public class MySimpleNotification extends Activity{
       DatabaseConnection connection;
      @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.my_simple_notification);
    connection=new DatabaseConnection(this);

    int notifID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NotifID");
    //int res=(int)connection.saveToTransaction(notifID); 
    //---PendingIntent to launch activity if the user selects 
    // the notification---
    Intent i = new Intent(MySimpleNotification.this,TransactionNotification.class);
    i.putExtra("NotifID", notifID);
    //i.putExtra("rowID", res);

    PendingIntent detailsIntent = 
        PendingIntent.getActivity(MySimpleNotification.this, 0, i, 0);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
        getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notif = new Notification(
        R.drawable.icon, 
        "New Transaction",
        System.currentTimeMillis());

    CharSequence from = "Daily expense :: Transaction";
    CharSequence message = "New Transaction is saved";

  ***AQUÍ ME MARCA EL ERROR--> notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, 
   detailsIntent);

    //---100ms delay, vibrate for 250ms, pause for 100 ms and
    // then vibrate for 500ms---
    notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500};        
    nm.notify(notifID, notif);
    finish();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Error 2:

```
           error: cannot find symbol method 
          setLatestEventInfo(Context,String,String,PendingIntent)
```

Trozo de código del 2do error

```
     public class NotifyService extends Service{

final static String ACTION = "NotifyServiceAction";
final static String STOP_SERVICE = "";
final static int RQS_STOP_SERVICE = 1;
static int count=0;
NotifyServiceReceiver notifyServiceReceiver;

private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private Notification myNotification;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//notifyServiceReceiver = new NotifyServiceReceiver();
super.onCreate();


}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

//IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
//intentFilter.addAction(ACTION);
//registerReceiver(notifyServiceReceiver, intentFilter);

// Send Notification


    notificationManager =
             (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
              "Notification!",
              System.currentTimeMillis());
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            String notificationTitle = "New Transaction";
            String notificationText = "new transaction occurs";
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MySimpleNotification.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent
              = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),
                0, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

          AQUÍ ME MARCA EL ERROR->myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context,
               notificationTitle,
               notificationText,
               pendingIntent);
            //myNotification.number++;
            notificationManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), 
   myNotification);
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
this.unregisterReceiver(notifyServiceReceiver);
super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

public class NotifyServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 int rqs = arg1.getIntExtra("RQS", 0);
 if (rqs == RQS_STOP_SERVICE){
  stopSelf();
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido user3802101, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Como se puede ver aquí [setLatestEventInfo:](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification)

*El método setLatestEventInfo ha sido eliminado de la clase Notification.*

Para crear una notificación utiliza la clase Notification.Builder de la siguiente manera:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new 
Notification.Builder(MyRemiderService.this);
.....
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable. notification_template_icon_bg)
   .setContentTitle("ContentTitle")
   .....
   .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);

Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.notification_template_icon_bg, 
notification);
```

Respuesta obtenida de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32564288/7856247

Answer (score -1):

El método `Notification.setLatestEventInfo()` fue removido en API 23 si tu proyecto esta configurado con un target mayor a esta API no funcionará, en realidad la mejor opción es cambiar la forma de crear la notificación y no bajar el nivel de la API.

[Revisa los cambios para la API 23, Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-notifications)

> **Notificaciones** En esta versión se quita el método `Notification.setLatestEventInfo()`. Usa la clase Notification.Builder,
>   en lugar de crear notificaciones. **Para actualizar una notificación de
>   manera repetida, reutiliza la instancia de `Notification.Builder`. Llama
>   al método `build()` para obtener instancias de Notification
>   actualizadas.**

Puedes usar ademas de la clase [NotificationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder) en lugar de `Notification` para compatibilidad entre versiones.

Agrego un método para crear Notificaciones:

```
   private void sendNotification(String message) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                        .setContentText(message);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

y un [ejemplo mas completo de lo que puedes realizar con las notificaciones](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Notifications):

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.